# Opacity CSS doesn't work in IE7/8, trying to put a transparent input button onto an image to make a custom input button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an opacity button onto an image. This is my code:

```
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('http://mysite.com/myimage.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#submit
{
position: absolute;
top: 354px;
left: 345px;
width: 112px;
height: 35px;
cursor:pointer;
opacity:0;
}
</style>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
```

My button image is on the background image that means I only have one image that is mysite.com/myimage.jpg , there is a button image on it. (button image is not a seperate slice).

It works very well in FF or Chrome, but it doesn't work in IE.. 
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Update, this works:#submit
{
position: absolute;
top: 354px;
left: 345px;
width: 112px;
height: 35px;
cursor:pointer;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE8 and earlier use something like:`filter:alpha(opacity=40);`

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp